# Batch: Extract string with batchRex.exe and store in variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this snippet and asking why it is not working (outputting empty). Is it a problem with this special batchRex.exe or do I have an error in my script?

```
set "workspace=C:\Projects\myProject"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ('batchRex.exe /file:"%workspace%\AssemblyInfo.cs" /pattern:"AssemblyFileVersion\("^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+^)"') do set VAR=%%i
echo %VAR%
```

Content of file AssemblyInfos.cs:

```
...
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("01.01.01.01")]
....
```

I want to have set only this string 01.01.01.01, that is the version, in a variable.

batchRex.exe: https://www.administrator.de/wissen/batchrex-regular-expressions-batch-nutzen-oder-extrahiert-bestimmten-text-212057.html

If someone have an alternative way to extract this string it is also ok, but I should be executed with a command in batch file script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need for regex here, if `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(` is unique:

```
@echo off
set "workspace=C:\Projects\myProject"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=()" %%i in ('type "%workspace%\AssemblyInfo.cs"^|findstr /b /c:"[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("') do set ver=%%i
echo %ver:"=%
```

`/b` means, the searchstring has to be at the beginning of the line
`/c` means, take the following string as a whole (per default, it would search any line that starts with `[assembly:` OR `AssemblyFileVersion(`

Comment: Thank you @Stephan for your answer. How can I tell that it should look in file AssemblyInfo.cs?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I've tried your edit and got ouput: "=

Comment: arghh - another typo (`(` instead of `/`)

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks a lot!